# Copying an SQLite Table Applying Default Values

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-insert

I have an SQLite database in my Android app that I would like to update. The update requires a change of datatype from INT to FLOAT. I understand the way to achieve this in SQLite is to create a new table, copy the data, and then replace the old table with the new one. Copying would be done as follows:

```
INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM oldTable
```

where integer values would be conveniently converted into floating point values.

Now, there is the problem that another, previously optional column is now ´NOT NULL´ but has a default value. I would like to have all NULL instances replaced by the default as part of the above process using the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM oldTable ON CONFLICT REPLACE
```

or, for completeness, in Android/Kotlin:

```
db.execSQL(“INSERT INTO newTable SELECT * FROM oldTable ON CONFLICT REPLACE”)
```

This gives me a syntax error, and I could not find a suitable example elsewhere. What would be the correct syntax to achieve this - and is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation for `INSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html), you'll see it should be `INSERT OR REPLACE ...`, and, yes, it'll work to replace null values in the not-null column with the default value.

[Replace conflict resolution documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html):

> When a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE algorithm deletes pre-existing rows that are causing the constraint violation prior to inserting or updating the current row and the command continues executing normally. **If a NOT NULL constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE conflict resolution replaces the NULL value with the default value for that column**, or if the column has no default value, then the ABORT algorithm is used. If a CHECK constraint or foreign key constraint violation occurs, the REPLACE conflict resolution algorithm works like ABORT.

---

Example:

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE foo(x, y NOT NULL DEFAULT 1);
sqlite> INSERT INTO foo(x,y) VALUES ('a', null);
Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: foo.y
sqlite> INSERT OR REPLACE INTO foo(x,y) VALUES ('a', null);
sqlite> SELECT * FROM foo;
x           y         
----------  ----------
a           1
```

Comment: Thank you. The table copy indeed works this way. One side-effect though: Other non-null columns that do not have a default value defined cause this statement to fail. I wonder if that can be avoided. When there is no meaningful default, not specifying it actually helps spotting programming errors.

Comment: @jerry You can't store a null value in a not-null column. Without a default value to use instead, of course it'd fail. What else is it supposed to do?

Comment: True, but the odd thing here is that it throws a null error when trying to copy non-null values from the source table to the same column in the destination table. Not-null columns don't necessarily require default values. There are a couple of such columns in my table where there is no meaningful default, and not specifying it can actually help spotting logical errors. Now, if the program fails to set the value a possibly wrong default is silently used.

Comment: Playing around with this a bit more it turns out that the statement `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO newTable SELECT * FROM oldTable` has the described side-effect while `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO newTable(Col1, Col2, ...) SELECT Col1, Col2, ...`copies the other not-null columns without problems. I don't have the insight to explain this, so I won't post it as an answer. This might be costly. But along with @Shawn's answer, it solves my problem.